# Почему listView.getCheckedItemPositions() глючит?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Почему `listView.getCheckedItemPositions()` глючит?

```
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, str));
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            int selected[] = new int[sparseBooleanArray.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < sparseBooleanArray.size(); i++) {
                selected[i] = sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i);
            }

            for (int i=0; i<selected.length; i++){
                switch (selected[i]){
                    case 0: new SmsMms(); break;
                    case 1: new Viber(); break;
                    case 2: new Skype(); break;
                    case 3: new WhatsApp(); break;
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Если запустить проект и ничего не нажимать то `sparseBooleanArray.size` равен `0`. Если же нажать на элемент любой и еще раз чтобы выключить галочку то `sparseBooleanArray` = 1. Глюк в методе `getCheckedItemPositions`. Почему `listView` себя не о обновляет каждый раз когда идет нажатие на элемент?

Результат 1 мне показал debugger Если что. Это специально для Pavlofff

Comment: Незнание API Android поможет вам найти еще очень много "глюков" и "багов". Не стесняйтесь, пишите сразу в багтрекер гугла.

Comment: @pavlofff, В StartAndroid этот пример работает, 54 урок. Я же этот код использовал не раз и всегда работало. Как вы думаете почему перетсал работать метод?

Comment: Так sparseBooleanArray обновляется же только по клику у вас

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, ну да. Точнее не обновляется а берет данные из getCheckedItemPositions. Но ведь когда я нажимаю на элемент в listView ведь галочка пропадает и появляется же, значит она хранится где то, тобишь в listView. Все верно

Comment: Навесьте событие на галочку, в нем пропишите sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();, увидите что значение будет меняться

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, на какую галочку?

listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, str));

Я стандартный способ использую. Адаптер стандартный

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, это все не то. SparseBooleanArray отображает все выделенные и измененные элементы, А мне нужны только выделенные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем кто в будущем столкнется с этим вот решение.

Дело в том что getCheckedItemPositions ищет не только как по логике должно быть включенные галки. А включенные элементы списка и элементы с которых снимали галки.

```
if (sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(i)){
       selected.add(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i));
}
```

Делаем такую проверку которая проверяет только true. Если галка выбрана то добавлям. Вот как то так), всем спасибо за помощь